# Objective-c : Execute a function in current class only after NSURLSession and NSXMLParser delegates complete in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a **Class1** in which I have to load a `UITableView` row on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. In this `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i make a call to a method in **Class2** which thereby calls `NSURLSession` delegates and `NSXMLParser` delegates. 
I want to get the value of this parsed data and reload the `UITableView` row in **Class1**.

I want to reload `UITableView` only after I get the data. 
As the Delegate methods are asynchronous I am not able to get the data and so I get an empty UITableView row.

What can be the solution?

Comment: Pass a closure to the method in class 2 that is invoked once the data is fetched. This closure can update the cell

Comment: you need to use call back function or closure in your class2 so when your  NSXMLParser and URL session work's done then in that function you need to call table reload and other data to your class1. you can also create delegate of class 1 so in your class 2 when the URLSession completed and you get data then call that delegate method and inside that delegate method you can reload your table data

Comment: Never worked with closure before.. so will have to check that out first..

Comment: Use delegate pattern or completion handlers to get the result back on expected class.

Answer (score 0):

On completion of data pulling and parsing in Class2, let Class1 know:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kDataIsReady" object:@{@"key":@"value"}];
```

You need to register Class1 as a listener early on (e.g. in viewDidLoad):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataReady:) name:@"kDataIsReady" object:nil];
```

Which then calls this method in Class1:

```
-(void)dataReady:(NSNotification *)n {

    NSDictionary * d = n.object; 
    NSString * value = d[@"key"];
    //e.g. update your data array, refresh tableView / specific cell
}
```